# Controlling transitions between states in SMACH

Tags: actionlib, smach, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
i started working with SMACH few days ago and I was wondering how I could control the transition between my states from external events. For example a transition would be triggered by the event "voice detected" or "light turned on" which could be published to a topic. I'm aware that it is possible to use acitonlib with SMACH but the tutorial is really confusing and not clear and there is no complete working example as far as I know. I'm also working with a central state machine where many smaller states are nested. Somebody has an idea how to implement event driven state transitions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172513/controlling-transitions-between-states-in-smach/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-06-02

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If your external event is going to correspond to something being published on a topic, then you should look at [MonitorState](http://wiki.ros.org/smach/Tutorials/MonitorState).The python docs are [here](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/smach_ros/html/python/smach_ros.monitor_state.MonitorState-class.html).

---

Originally posted by [hawesie](https://answers.ros.org/users/246/hawesie/) with karma: 282 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-06-02**:
Thanks, this does what I need. I previously did it manually using an endless loop at the end of my state checking for a global variable that is changed to true in a callback function of a subscribed topic.